# Image won't center

Tags: html, css

I have looked through answers to similar questions and have attempted to use the suggestions made, however, img remains aligned left.

Below is the HTML

```
        <section>
            <img class="seattle" src="img/Seattle Pier.jpg" alt="Seattle docks">
  <h3>General Information</h3>
```

Here is the CSS

```
section {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.seattle {
  display: block;
  margin: 0, auto, 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: css syntax for margin https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `margin: 0, auto, 15px;` to `margin: 0 auto 15px;` it is call [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

```
.seattle {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

**Syntax**

```
margin: style                  /* One-value syntax   */  E.g. margin: 1em; 
margin: vertical horizontal    /* Two-value syntax   */  E.g. margin: 5% auto; 
margin: top horizontal bottom  /* Three-value syntax */  E.g. margin: 1em auto 2em; 
margin: top right bottom left  /* Four-value syntax  */  E.g. margin: 2px 1em 0 auto; 

margin: inherit
```

Comment: I totally skimmed over those commas in the margin property. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple. you can add selector img in section:

```
section img{
   margin:0 auto;
   /*this follows can be set again*/
   margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```